# set og tags for homepage only

Tags: php, html, facebook, joomla

i have a problem with og tags.
i added on my template index a string like

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/facebook.jpg" />
```

to fix an image for the site when shared on facebook because otherwise strange images where chosen by facebook. But this conflicts with all my blog articles pages when shared on facebook. And the og tag image override the blog image when my article is shared.
I need help  to set the og tags in the template index.php to work only for my homepage.

They suggested me something like

```
if($currentPage == 'home' || $currentPage == 'article'){
codeSampleToAddSocialShare()
}
```

but i really can't make it my myself, i don't know where to put the code and if it's correct or just an example.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Gonna go out on a limb and assume this is WordPress?  Add the tag if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to edit the template directly, here is a conditional check you can do to see if the homepage is being displayed:

(Assuming you are using Joomla 2.5 or 3.x. See this [link](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page) for more info & other versions)

```
<?php
  $app = JFactory::getApplication();
  $menu = $app->getMenu();
  if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
      echo '<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/facebook.jpg" /> ';
  }
?>
```

Ideally, you would create a plugin to add the meta tag to your HTML HEAD so updates to your template do not overwrite your changes.